# Which Labeling should I use for my data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pandas

I am currently getting ready to preprocess my data for scikitlearn and was wondering if I should use one hot encoding or label encoding when working with values greater than 9. I may be wrong but when it comes to one hot encoding it can only work on values 0-9.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, depends on the model you are going to use later. If you are planning to use a tree-based model, then label-encoding (or even frequency-encoding) works fine. However, if you plan on using a linear model or Neural network, then one-hot encoding works better. Using one-hot encoding in tree-based models might unnecessarily increase complexity (See [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-hot-encoding-is-making-your-tree-based-ensembles-worse-heres-why-d64b282b5769)).

Always strategize  your preprocessing so that it benefits the model you have chosen.

Comment: I plan on using several models (Random Forest, Clustering, and Regression).

Comment: Separately preprocess for each of them. Using the same preprocessed data for all algorithms is never advised.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the meaning of the feature.

- If sorting labels makes sense  `LabelEncoder`/`OrdinalEncoder` is better choice (for example feature is `damage in ["no", "light", "medium", "severe"]`)
- Otherwise `OneHotEncoder` is a better choice (for example `color in ["blue", "yellow", "orange"]`)